# Question about offset values in C code to MIPS assembly conversion

Tags: c, mips

My task is to Translate the following C code to MIPS assembly code. At the beginning of this code segment, the base address of arrays A and B are in registers $t2 and $t3, the starting index “i” is a positive integer in register $s0, and the loop boundary 50 in register $t1.

By what method can I be certain the offset values used in lw instructions are correct to access the "Data" variable?

```
    int A[50], B[50];
    while (i < 50) {
       B[i] = A[i+1] - B[i-1];
       i = i+2;
    }
```

Here is what I currently have:

```
    loop:
        lw $s1, 4($t2)          # load A[i+1] 
        lw $s2, -4($t3)         # load B[i-1] 
        sub $t4, $s1, $s2       # A[i+1] - B[i-1] 
        sw $t4, 0(t3)           # B[i] = A[i+1] - B[i-1] 
        addi $t2, $t2, 8        # i = i+2 for A 
        addi $t3, $t3, 8        # i = i+2 for B 
        addi $s0, $s0, 2        # increment index by 2 i = i +2 
        slt $at, $a2, $t1       # $at = 1(set) if i < 50; $at = 0(clear) if i >= 50; 
        bne $at, $0, loop       # if (i < 50) go to loop
```

Comment: It sounds like you have some code written already. Can you share that?

Comment: Don't post code in comments. Update your question. And also tell us what the problem is.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/833vTq) is useful for some point, but unfortunately specifying assignment of registers to variables seems difficult on that.

Comment: @RetiredNinja yes, I have updated my question with the code

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch ya, I tried Compiler Explorer but it doesn't allow me to specify register

Comment: And, what is **your** question? What you have after "question" is the task you are given.

Comment: @thebusybee I am quite confused about lw instruction and am not sure if I am using the offset correctly to access `Data`. sorry, just updated the question